# Why are the results of "docker stats" different when input from host and container?

Tags: docker, containers

I'm developing an application that monitors the memory of a container. And the application itself is also in Docker.

However, the memory usage seen on the host machine is different from the memory usage seen inside the container. The command used is as follows.

```sh
$ docker stats --no-stream --all --format "{{.Name}}\t{{.Container}}\t{{.CPUPerc}}\t{{.MemUsage}}"
mysql   56f0dcbdf2e2    0.48%   435.9MiB / 1.943GiB
```

It's like seeing RSS from the host and VSS from inside the container. Can you please explain about it?